# roles overides tasks in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have ansible playbook which look similar to the code below :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
 connection: local

 tasks:
 - name: "Create custom fact directory
   file:
    path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
    state: "directory"

 - name: "Insert  custom fact file"
   copy:
    src:  custom_fact.fact
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/custom_fact.fact
    mode: 0755

roles:
- role1
- role2
```

once i am running the playbook with ansible-playbook command
only the roles  is running ,but the tasks is not getting ran

if i am remarking the roles  from the playbook,the task gets ran

how can i make the task to run before the roles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the tasks in a section `pre_tasks` which are run before roles.

You may also find `post_tasks` useful which run tasks after roles.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the indentation

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: "Create custom fact directory
      file:
        path: ...
```